# Como fazer update no banco ao reordenar lista por sortable

Tags: mysql, jquery-ui, sortable

### Daew rapazianda, tô utilizando o sortable para reordenar uma lista. Como eu faço a alteração no banco dentro da função? Segue o meu código:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['clienteLogado']=="") {
        header("Location:login.php");
    }
    require_once("function.php");

    $idPesquisa=$_GET['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pergunta p WHERE pesq_id=". $idPesquisa . " and perg_exclusao = 1 order by perg_ordem";
    $resultado = $MySQLi->query($sql) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
            $("#sortable").sortable({
                stop: function(event, ui) {

                 //REORDENAÇÃO

                }
            });
            $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
            });

    </script>
```

Vlw pela ajuda!

Comment: Não deu pra entender qual o objetivo da pergunta, especifique mais.

Comment: Quer ordenar os campos de uma coluna em ordem alfabética e gravar no banco?

Comment: por exemplo:
eu tenho uma lista...

id | nome | idade
1  | joão   | 22
2  | maria | 18
3  | joana | 23

com o drag and drop eu quero mudar essa sequência, portanto eu arrasto o id 2 pra cima salvando o novo id no banco e reordenando o resto da lista.